# Probability - blood test

Tags: probability

> The blood type distribution in the UK is: type A, 41%, type B, 9% type AB, 4% type O, 46%. It is estimated that every year, 4% of surgery patients with type O are classed as having type A, 88% of those with type A are correctly classed, 4% with type B are classed as type A, and 10% of those with type AB are classed as type A. Now a patient comes in surgery and is classed as having type A blood. What is the probability that this is his actual blood type?

This is how I interpreted the question

$P( A) = 0.41 ~,~ P(B) = 0.09 ~,~ P(AB) = 0.04~,~ P(O) = 0.46$

$P(A\mid O) = 0.04 ~,~ P(A\mid C) = 0.88\cdot 0.41$ or is it $0.88$ $P(A\mid B) = 0.04 ~,~ P(A\mid AB) = 0.01$

$P(C\mid A) = P(A\mid C) \cdot P(C ) / P(A)$

But it doesn’t make sense

Comment: So the answer is 88% of type A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between classed blood type ($Xc$) and real blood type ($X$), where $X\in \{A,B,AB, 0\}$

$P(A)=0.41, P(B)=0.09,P(AB)=0.04,P(0)=0.46$

Thus $P(Ac|0)=0.04,P(Ac|A)=0.88,P(Ac|B)=0.04, P(Ac|AB)=0.10$

Then $$P(A|Ac)=\frac{P(Ac|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(Ac)}$$

$$=\frac{P(Ac|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(A)\cdot P(Ac|A)+P(B)\cdot P(Ac|B)+P(AB)\cdot P(Ac|AB)+P(0)\cdot P(Ac|0)}$$

For the denominator the law of total probability has been applied.